# Drupal 7 Views table style with exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I want to place my exposed views filters in a tabular format, something like below

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is in the theme layer.

One way would be to implement a theme override - probably with a hook_preprocess function, maybe also hook_form_alter. Embedding the form in a table will be particularly tricky, since the exposed filter and results table are rendered in distinct processes.

If you are comfortable with jQuery, it might be easier to do this with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a similar problem. As I understand it Theming exposed filters and tables are at different levels. The exposed filter is disclosed in views-view.tpl.php, it is the same conclusion as the content , I think that this variable has generated a table or row. The output is in the same table views-view-table.tpl.php. I do not have enough practice at it, but I think that it is necessary to develop a plug-in for vieschs and it override the views-view.tpl.php where instead of  Display a table and has already exposed within this place filters. I do not know if that is right?

P.S. this text translated by google translator.

Answer (score 0):

The module that you are looking for is [Views Table Filter.](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_table_filter)

The module page reads

> This module allows to move views exposed filters in table header if
>   view display is table. The configuration for this option is in Better
>   Exposed Filters configuration form, so the module depends on BEF.